# ngOnChanges && @Input after dropdown change data not updated

Tags: node.js, angular

I have an parent **SiliComponent** and child **SiliChildComponent**.

Within SiliChildComponent I have an @Input() expdays:any[];

This is added within ngOnChanges interfaces like this:

**Angular4 SiliChildComponent**

```
 data:any; 
 @Input() expdays:any[];
 ngOnChanges() {
 this.data = this.expdays;
 }
```

**HTML from parent component SiliComponent **

```
    <select (ngModelChange)="changeCar($event)">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="vw">VW</option>
      <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
    </select>

   <expdays [expdays]='exp_searchData'></expdays>
```

**HTML from child component SiliChildComponent where I am using the @Input data**

```
<div *ngFor="let x of data" > 
{{x}}
</div>
```

**Fixed problem:
The issue was in another place of my code.**

Comment: where are you using that input?

Comment: I added more information

Comment: Actually I meant where are you assigning `expdays` in the child component from the parent component, could you add that as well?

Comment: I see. whithin expdays selector. See above

Comment: Would it be possible to create a plunker demonstrating the behaviour? [Here's a template to get started](https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=catalogue)

Comment: There is not enough information, for example, what does `changeCar($event)` do?